# Balancing Parenthesis Algorithm Using Stacks

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

So I am learning on Data Structures and Algorithms currently working on Stacks, Queues and Dequeus

I have this question that says I should implement a Stack to check if the string given has balanced parenthesis and I am told in the question that the string contains `only` parenthesis and the string has `no spaces`

So I did implement my Stack class and then tried solving the problem `Checking if the Parenthesis balance` and I did a simple test case `'[]'` and it return False instead of `True`
So I fail to spot the error in the code.

**Below is my thought process to solving the question so you can clearly see where I could have went wrong:**

1. Firstly I checked if the length of the string is even if not I return `False`
2. I scan through the string and every time I see an opening parenthesis I push it to the stack
3. Then when I see a closing parenthesis I use the knowledge of stacks that LIFO I know that if now I am seeing a closing parenthesis the previous one should be the corresponding opening which was the last item pushed to stack so I then pop it off the stack and save it into a variable
4. I then make a check if they correspond and if they do not I return `False`
5. I then check if the stack is Empty then I know the is no corresponding opening parenthesis I return `False`
6. Finally if the loop finished without any return I check if stack is empty I return `True` else I `False`

**Code Below**

```
class Stack(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def isEmpty(self):

        return self.items == 0

    def get_size(self):

        return len(self.items)


    def push(self, data):

        self.items.append(data)

    def peek(self):

        return self.items[len(self)-1]

    def remove_item(self):

        self.items.pop()


stack = Stack()


def balance_check(s):

    if len(s) % 3 == 0:
        return False


    openings = set('({[')
    matches = set([ ('{', '}') , ('(', ')') , ('[', ']') ])

    for paren in s:

        if paren in openings:
            stack.push(paren)


        else:

            if stack.get_size() == 0:
                return False

            last_open = stack.remove_item()

            if (last_open, paren) not in matches:

                return False

    if stack.get_size() == 0:
        return True


print(balance_check('[]'))
```

Comment: `len(s) % 3 == 0` is checking for the length being a multiple of three, NOT that it is even...  That's not a necessary check anyway, any lack of balance would be detected by the stack.

Comment: `len(s) % 3 == 0` checks if length can be divided by 3, not if it is even.

Comment: `remove_item` returns nothing (actually "None").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great attempt. You were very close. Just a couple of issues or typos.

1. `remove_item()` removed the item from the list, but not returned.
2. odd/even check is done by `% 2 == 1`, not `% 3`.

```
class Stack(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == 0
    def get_size(self):
        return len(self.items)
    def push(self, data):
        self.items.append(data)
    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items)-1]
    def remove_item(self):
        # you were not returning here
        return self.items.pop()

stack = Stack()

def balance_check(s):
    # odd/even check is done like this, not by % 3
    if len(s) % 2 == 1:
        return False

    openings = set('({[')
    matches = set([('{', '}'), ('(', ')'), ('[', ']')])

    for paren in s:
        if paren in openings:
            stack.push(paren)
        else:
            if stack.get_size() == 0:
                return False
            last_open = stack.remove_item()
            if (last_open, paren) not in matches:
                return False

    # simplified return
    return stack.get_size() == 0


print(balance_check('{[]{()}}'))
```

You can add more quick checks like:

1. If string starts with closing parenthesis, return False
2. If String ends with opening parenthesis, return False

Answer (score -2):

Your algorithm is wrong, since this is not a valid string: `"]]]][[[["`

instead, every time you see an open parenthesis, you push onto the stack, a closed parenthesis gets popped, if the length is 0 before the string is exhausted, the answer is "false", if the length is NOT zero when the string is exhausted, the answer is "false". Otherwise, "true".

Comment: `"]]]][[[["` is returned as `False` by the algorithm.